# Why am I getting message that provider must return value from factory $get method?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

So, I have a suite of tests for angular, using jasmine and karma. I have a module for lodash and moment defined like this

```
(function (angular) {

    var lodash = angular.module('lodash', []);

    lodash.factory('_', ['$window', function ($window) {
        //lodash must already be loaded on the page 

        var _ = $window._;

        delete ($window._);

        return _ ;
    }]);

    var moment = angular.module('moment', []);

    moment.factory('moment',['$window',function ($window) {

        var toReturn = $window.moment;

        delete ($window.moment);

        return toReturn;
    }]);

})(angular);
```

This all works without problems in my app. Why am I getting this message, when obiously, I am returning a "_" object from the method?

Example of usage

```
(function (angular) {

    'use strict';

    var controllerId = 'batchSearchCtrl';

    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, batchSearchCtrl);

    batchSearchCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'batchSearchViewModel', 'modalSvc', '_'];

    function batchSearchCtrl($scope, $routeParams, batchSearchViewModel, modalSvc, _ ) {
  }
})(angular);
```

here is a karma file (not complete file just part dealing with loading of the files)

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
        basePath: '../app',

        // frameworks to use
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
          'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.js'
        , 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular-resource.js'
        , 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular-route.js'
        , 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular-animate.js'

        , '../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'

        , '../components/**/*.js'

        , '../scripts/sinon-1.7.3.js'
        , '../scripts/base64.js'

        , '../scripts/moment-2.4.0.js/moment-with-langs.js'
        , '../scripts/watch-1.3.0.js/watch.js'
        , '../scripts/jquery/jquery.js'
        , '../scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.js'
        , '../scripts/ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js'
        , '../scripts/lodash/lodash-3.0.0.js'
        , '../scripts/watch/watch-1.3.0.js'

        , '../scripts/scriptModules.js'
        , '../common/module.js'
        , 'app.js'

        , '../common/*.js'
        , '../common/**/*.js'

        , '*.js' // all js files in root app folder
        , 'app_directives/**/*.js'
        , 'batch/*.js'
        , 'batch/closing/*.js'
        , 'batch/search/*.js'
        , 'batch/summary/*.js'
 });
};
```

Comment: Just a hunch: Sometimes in the `beforeEach()` of a test, you want to inject a service/factory and reference it in your tests with a local variable of the same name. You can do that w/syntax like this: `var $compile; beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_) { $compile = _$compile_; }));` I'm guessing your service named `_` is having the "_" stripped from it's name in order to support the above injection syntax.

Comment: What does your `karma.conf` look like? You should be loading `lodash` and `moment` through it right after loading `angular-mock`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went out on a limb in the comments, and after a little digging I believe that I am right. The "_" is being stripped from your service name in test by the [mock injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject).

Specifically, read the section [Resolving References (Underscore Wrapping)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject#resolving-references-underscore-wrapping-):

> To help with this, the injected parameters can, optionally, be enclosed with underscores. These are ignored by the injector when the reference name is resolved.

I can't seem to find the actual [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js) that is doing this. However, my diagnosis seems to be supported by these two facts:

- You use the same technique to declare the service for moment.js, and do not have any problems
- The problem only occurs in tests, where the mock injector uses/supports underscore wrapping.

**EDIT:**

**Potential work around for tests:**

In the test code when you create your controller, use the underscore wrapping technique to retrieve your lodash service, something like this:

```
var controller, scope;
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, ___) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  controller = $controller('batchSearchCtrl', {$scope: scope, _: ___});
}));
```

Comment: I switched all my declarations for that I use 'lodash' as module name, and then in file before anything I declare variable var _ = lodash;  All my tests are working now :)